# Problem with annuity program: too few arguments

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program to work out a math equation to find annuity. the formula is as shown 
`A = M=[(1+r)^n-1/r(1+r)^n]` .
 The program compiler I am using is Devcpp it its worked with my other programs and i cannot find the error in this one. it tells me that there are too few arguments in the line with the formula.

any help is greatly appreciated :)

the code is:

```
double M, r, n;

cout<<"M = ";
cin>>M;

cout<<"r = ";
cin>>r;

cout<<"n = ";
cin>>n;

cout<<endl;

cout<<"A = M=[(1+r)^n-1/r(1+r)^n]";
cout<<endl<<endl;

cout<<"A = ";
cout<<(M * ( pow ((( 1 + r ), n ) - 1 )/(r * ((pow(1 + r), n)))));
```

Comment: Please read: http://www.jasonbadams.net/20081218/why-you-shouldnt-use-dev-c/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It appears you have your question answered.  Please click the check next to the answer to accept it.  This will remove it from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cout<<(M * ( pow ((( 1 + r ), n ) - 1 )/(r * ((pow(1 + r), n)))));
```

You're passing just one argument to the outer`pow`  call. Where is the second argument?

Why don't you simply it? Why did you make it so unreadable that even you cannot read and understand it properly? If you can't understand it yourself, how will others understand it?

Probably you want to do this:

```
double r1 = pow (1 + r,n-1 );
double r2 = pow (1 + r,n)
double A =  M * r1/ (r * r2);
cout<< A;
```

Based on what I could understand, I wrote this. Is it correct? Do it similarly if you wanted slightly different calculation. **But must do it in *simple* steps**. That is good for you as well as for those who will read your code.

Comment: Thanks, im just very new to programming. and i did something similar that was much simpler and it worked with a different program i wrote. and once again thanks, it did help a lot.